# How to substract one large vector by another?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, math, theano

I want to calculate the vectored difference between two vectors of great dimension. Both are columns of a dataframe.
I am able to subtract a list of arrays to an array and put it to the power of 2

```
(train["quest_emb"][0] - train["sent_emb"][0])**2
```

but not to generalize it with a dataframe column of lists of arrays to a dataframe of arrays :

```
train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"]
```

as it freeze my computer.

#### Array analysis

Here is an example of their contents.

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2]))
[[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2]))
[array([0.03037658, 0.04433101, 0.08135635, ..., 0.06764812, 0.04971079,
       0.02240689], dtype=float32), array([0.05260669, 0.04548098, 0.0382337 , ..., 0.04823414, 0.07656007,
       0.03501297], dtype=float32), array([0.0502927 , 0.04480611, 0.02038252, ..., 0.03942193, 0.03132772,
       0.04595207], dtype=float32), array([0.06769167, 0.03393815, 0.0625218 , ..., 0.05555448, 0.03059104,
       0.03422254], dtype=float32)]
```

It seems there is a difference of size :

```
>>> print(len(train["quest_emb"][0]))
1
>>> print(len(train["sent_emb"][0]))
4
```

Here are their types, different but it doesn't seem to make any problem when substractinge a line aby another:

```
>>> print((train["quest_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03949683 0.04509903 0.01808935 ... 0.04610749 0.0416535  0.02240689]

>>> print((train["sent_emb"][2][0]))
[0.03037658 0.04433101 0.08135635 ... 0.06764812 0.04971079 0.02240689]
```

The length of `train["quest_emb"]` is the same with `train["sent_emb"]` : 130318

Here are the types of the arrays

```
>>> print(type(train["quest_emb"][2]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> print(type(train["sent_emb"][2]))
<class 'list'>
```

**Is there any way to make this difference computable for a computer with 8G of RAM ? Or if not an approximate way?**

#### Attempt with Theano

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x - y
f = function([x, y], z)   
f(train["quest_emb"],train["sent_emb"])
```

But it gave me

```
ValueError: Bad input argument with name "quest_emb" to theano function with name "<ipython-input-41-c53eb459cbc4>:6" at index 0 (0-based).
```

As far as I can compute one line after the other, I'm also thinking about doing this vector subtraction iteratively but I don't know how I can add up a new line to a dataframe after each subtractions.

Comment: I am not familiar with Theano, but if it is just vector subtraction, cant you do with a single loop.